# How to play audio in javascript in any recent web browser... and distribute the encoder?

Tags: javascript, flash, audio

I can't find a way to play back audio in any recent browser, using javascript, especially if I want to be able to distribute an audio encoder to create the audio files (which forbids mp3 format). The audio files could be either on the server or stored locally. The issues are:

- Using the HTML5 audio tag, with a flash fallback libraries (such as [jplayer](http://www.jplayer.org/), soundmanager2 or projekktor) is easy but the only format that would work anywhere is mp3.
- I could use speex/flv but it would only work with flash, forbidding iphone/ipad.
- A plain wav file would not work on IE 8, 7, 6

A reasonable list of recent browser to be supported is: IE 8-9, FF 4, Chrome 11 and safari 4, including on iphone/ipad.

The only solutions I would see would be to implement a wav file player in flash, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091812/html-embeddable-flash-wav-player) (but I would have to learn how to program actionscript), or to encode the files in a free format, upload them, and re-incode them to MP3 on the server (but lot of server CPU load).

Do you know any solution without these drawbacks?

Comment: What do you mean by "distribute an audio encoder" exactly? What's wrong with MP3? Are you looking to implement DRM?

Comment: Due to patent restrictions, you have to pay license fees in order to distribute MP3 encoders: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#Licensing_and_patent_issues